# how to find product not in correct location in sql

Tags: sql

how to find products that are within the same package, given the constraints of physics, it must be present at the same location within the warehouse.

sample schema

```sql
    CREATE TABLE stock (
        id SERIAL,
        product_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES products ( id ),
        location_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES locations ( id ),
        package_id integer REFERENCES packages ( id ),
        qty integer
      );
      insert into stock values (1,1,1,1,1) ;
      insert into stock values (2,2,1,1,1) ;
      insert into stock values (3,3,2,1,1) ;
      insert into stock values (4,4,2,1,1) ;
      insert into stock values (5,1,2,1,1) ;
      insert into stock values (6,1,3,1,1) ;
```

my query

```sql
    select package_id from (
    select count(*), t2.product_id, t2.package_id
    from stock t2
    group by t2.product_id, t2.package_id
    having count(*)>1
      ) t3 ;


    select t4.* from stock t4,
    (
    select count(*), t1.package_id, t1.location_id 
    from stock t1
    where t1.package_id in (select package_id from (
    select count(*), t2.product_id, t2.package_id
    from stock t2
    group by t2.product_id, t2.package_id
    having count(*)>1
      ) t3 )
    group by t1.package_id, t1.location_id
    having count(*)>1) t5
    where t5.package_id = t4.package_id and t5.location_id = t4.location_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
select s.*
from stock s
where exists (select 1
              from stock s2
              where s2.package_id = s.package_id and
                    s2.location_id <> s.location_id
             );
```

If you want just the packages, aggregation is easy:

```
select package_id
from stock s
group by package_id
having min(location_id) <> max(location_id);
```